# Azure Synapse Studio: Different number of columns in CREATE TABLE or CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and SELECT query

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I have a need to run a query against a large dataset in Azure Synapse Studio. The results of the query will be far too large to return in the web interface, so I've been looking at how to pipe the results to an external file.

I was following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/create-use-external-tables) but facing an issue which I've broken down to the following simply query:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestCsv
(
    [CustomerId] VARCHAR (10)
)
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'test.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = MyDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = QuotedCSVWithHeaderFormat
) AS
SELECT TOP 10 CustomerId
FROM dbo.Customers
```

Here, `MyDataSource` is a data source connection to an Azure storage blob container using a God SAS token.

The above query produces the following error:

> Different number of columns in CREATE TABLE or CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE and SELECT query.

I just don't understand what's wrong with this. FWIW the CustomerID column returned from the Customers view is also a *VARCHAR(10)*.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

External tables are similar to the normal except that it does not hold data . So in this case the table TestCsv reads all the data from the file "test.csv" .
I think you are confusing the below query as CTE , in TSQL world this should work fine .

```
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'test.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = MyDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = QuotedCSVWithHeaderFormat
) AS
SELECT TOP 10 CustomerId
FROM dbo.Customers
```

If the intend is to load the records from "dbo.Customers" in the external table "TestCsv" , just update the underlining csv file .

You can use the Synapse pipeline to records  the view to the file.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It appears that it gives the Error "Different number of columns" when you specify the column schema in the new EXTERNAL TABLE.  It can auto detect the column schema types from your SELECT statement, e.g.:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TestCsv
WITH (
    LOCATION = 'test.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = MyDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = QuotedCSVWithHeaderFormat
) AS
SELECT TOP 10 CustomerId
FROM dbo.Customers
```

Also see:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cetas-creating-external-table-as-select-in-azure-synapse-analytics/